# What is the correct way to create slave I2C using FreeRTOS on STM32?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, i2c, freertos, hal

I am new in ARM and try to create slave device on STM32F103x. Also I need Serial Wire debugging and FreeRTOS tasking.

I create new project by STM32CubeMX. There are options to "Use FreeRTOS functions" in NVIC configuration. But I did not find any documentation, references or demos about how to use that.

[image: stm32cube_nvic_options]

**EDIT 1:** So I make in such way for now:

```c
#include <string.h>

#define MASTER_REQ_READ   0x44
#define MASTER_REQ_EXEC   0x34

#define CONN_Pin GPIO_PIN_13
#define CONN_GPIO_Port GPIOC

/* Recieve protocol struct from Main controller */
struct saatProtoExec {
    uint8_t target;
    uint8_t command;
} execCommand;

uint8_t execBufferSize = sizeof(execCommand);


int main(void)
{
  /*******************************/

  /* definition and creation of i2cWait */  
  osThreadDef(i2cWait, i2cWaitForData, osPriorityRealtime, 0, 128);
  i2cWaitHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(i2cWait), NULL);

  osKernelStart();
  /* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }

}

/* i2cWaitForData function */
void i2cWaitForData(void const * argument)
{
    /* Infinite loop */
    for(;;)
    {
        while(HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT(&hi2c1, (uint8_t*)&bTransferRequest, 1)!= HAL_OK)
        {
            vTaskDelay(1);
        }

        /*  Wait for I2C to get ready */
        while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
        {
            vTaskDelay(1);
        }

        /* Got command from main controller */
        if (bTransferRequest == MASTER_REQ_EXEC)
        {
            /* Recieve buffer */
            uint8_t execRxBuffer[execBufferSize];
            printf("EXEC BUFFER SIZE %d\n", execBufferSize);

            /* Got data */
            while(HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT(&hi2c1, (uint8_t*)execRxBuffer, execBufferSize)!= HAL_OK);

            /*  Wait for I2C to get ready */
            while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
            {
                vTaskDelay(1);
            }

            /* Lets print recieved RAW data */
            for (uint8_t k = 0; k < sizeof(execRxBuffer); k++){
                printf("0x%X\n", execRxBuffer[k]);
            }

            /* Lets combine recieved data to owr struct */
            memcpy(&execCommand, execRxBuffer, execBufferSize);

            /* Lets print data from struct */
            printf("TARGET: 0x%X\n", execCommand.target);
            printf("COMMAND: %u\n", execCommand.command);

            /* Flush Rx buffers */
            Flush_Buffer((uint8_t*)execRxBuffer, execBufferSize);

            /* Toggle LED2 */
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(CONN_GPIO_Port, CONN_Pin);

        }

        osDelay(1);
    }
}
```

It works fine in non-blocking mode, but anyway: is it correct to do this?
Or may be it would be right to use Semaphores?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this user manual: [Developing Applications on STM32Cube with RTOS](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/2d/60/ff/15/8c/c9/43/77/DM00105262.pdf/files/DM00105262.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105262.pdf).

It has a description about FreeRTOS regarding the following points:

- Free RTOS source organizations
- Porting FreeRTOS on STM32
- FreeRTOS API
- FreeRTOS memory management
- FreeRTOS low power
- FreeRTOS configuration

Also it has application examples of the main operating system features:

- Thread creation example
- Semaphores example (between threads, from ISR)
- Mutexes example
- Queues example
- Timers example
- Low power example

There is an example project provided about thread creation in the [STM32CubeF1](https://my.st.com/content/my_st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcus-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32cube-embedded-software/stm32cubef1.license%3D1475082184464.html) package under:

```
\STM32Cube_FW_F1_V1.4.0\Projects\STM32F103RB-Nucleo\Applications\FreeRTOS\FreeRTOS_ThreadCreation
```

this example uses an STM32F103RB.

Comment: Well, I read it already, and played with FreeRTOS examples from STM32Cube. The question is what native FreeRTOS functions are used to read data by I2C on STM32? Can **HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT** be used in FreeRTOS thread?

Comment: I suppose. You could add though the Cube generated code, which uses FreeRTOS functions. I think the only criteria towards the OS is that it should be notified about the interrupts, so it can handle their priorities as well.

Comment: I added example in the topic. Is it correct to do in a such way?

Comment: If it is working that is a good start. But the interrupt handler of the I2C is being called somewhere by you or the OS? Unhandeled so unexpected interrupts can cause exceptions.

Comment: You are right, I am confused because of STM32Cube creates interrupt  `I2C1_ER_IRQHandler(void)` in **stm32f1xx_it.c**, but it never triggers. As I understand, **HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_IT** turns interrupt on during execution. I really do not like my code, it is ugly. I think, that it would be correct to recieve data by interrupt only and parse them in FreeRTOS task. What do you think?

Comment: Ups, I mean `I2C1_EV_IRQHandler`. But error interrupt too.

Comment: Are you sure it is never triggered? But I think you can stick to your current code, as it has the handler. As far as I know FreeRTOS allows interruptr, only it has some limitation about what OS functions can be called from an ISR, but this is not the case here.